# what is the difference between (class *object;) and (object = new Class();)?

Tags: c++, qt

I couldn't understand. Why we need both? What is the difference?

```
QTimer *timerobject;
timerobject = new QTimer(this);
```

Comment: We don't need both. `QTimer* timerobject = new QTimer(this);` is best.

Comment: Or not using `new` at all.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Note: This is Qt `QObject` subclass instance, which in this case has a parent. The parent will delete its children when it is destructed. So while indeed it's better to not use `new` with QObjects when possible (in other words, when object has no parent, or object's lifetime ends *before* its parent's), sometimes it is easiest, and especially safest for novice programmers, to just use `new` and let parent do `delete`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line is **declaration** - in your code you declared timerObject as a pointer to a QTimer type.

In the second line you performed a number of operations: You **allocated memory** for a QTimer variable, you **constructed** it, and then you **assigned** that QTimer variable's address to the pointer variable you created in the first line.

Also, you can write it in a single line:

```
QTimer * timerobject = new QTimer(this);
```

Both lines are necessary because if you would only declare the object, it wouldn't have any value. It would just point to nothing (nullptr). If you wouldn't declare it, the compiler wouldn't know what timerobject is, and so it wouldn't be able to assign any value to it.

Comment: Note that mostly pointers will not be initialized to any default value, so they won't usually be `nullptr`. They'll be whatever happened to be on the memory location reserved for the pointer variable (some exceptions, such as global variables, which will be 0 at program startup if not initialized).